# Microsoft SQL Server batch processing intermittent commit in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2017

I am trying to insert millions of records into a Microsoft SQL Server table from another table (with in the same Microsoft SQL Server) with batch number calculation using `row_number()` function as shown below.

```
CEILING((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ITEM,LOC))/CONVERT(FLOAT,'''
                       +CONVERT(VARCHAR(55),@PLANNING_BATCH_SIZE)+'''))-1+convert(float,'''+convert(varchar(55),@PREVIOUSEBATCHSIZE)+''' ) AS BATCH_NUM
```

Once all these records inserted into a table with Batch numbers, I will call a Java method to start another process by using each batch data.

Now to insert millions of records it is taking minutes of time, Java method has to wait until the whole insertion completes. My question is do we have any option in SQL Server to apply intermittent commits in
`INSERT INTO SELECT` query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert some rows, commit, and then start inserting another then you need to do it in batches. We have very little information to go on here, so this is a **very** simple pseudo-SQL  example of how you *might* insert data in small batches:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO YourDestinationTable ({COLUMNS})
SELECT TOP 1000
       {COLUMNS}
FROM YourSourceTable ST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM YourDestinationTable YD
                  WHERE YD.{IDENTITY COLUMN} = ST.{IDENTITY COLUMN});

COMMIT;

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO YourDestinationTable ({COLUMNS})
    SELECT TOP 1000
           {COLUMNS}
    FROM YourSourceTable ST
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM YourDestinationTable YD
                      WHERE YD.{IDENTITY COLUMN} = ST.{IDENTITY COLUMN});

    COMMIT;

END;
```